# cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances

Tags: python, html, django, influxdb

I want to see the type of a list element but I am not able to see this, it gives this error: `cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances`. Normally, it seems to keep dict but I cannot use the dict methods on this variable (like `.items`). So, I need to learn the type of it. This is the variable :

```
[
  {
    'time': '2021-07-03T15:44:40.124358Z', 
    'application_name': 'TrashTest', 
    'dev_eui': '45405201a0000009', 
    'device_name': 'sayac-001', 
    'f_port': '4', 
    'value': 338.0
  }
].
```

I want to use the value parameter only. How can I take the value? Thanks a lot. [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tgYn.png)
[and this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMjGM.png)

Comment: Hi Tommy, please provide us a code in a text form (not image form) and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your questions in a future :) Good luck and have a great day!